# Java sum a list of items based on properties

Tags: collections, java-8, java-stream

Given a class Item as below:

```
Class item {
 private Date date;
 private String id;
 private Double value;

 // getter and setter...
}
```

I would like to create a function that goes through a list of items and sum the value for the Items with the same date and id, and return the list of IDs and sum of value.

```
public Map<String, Double> process(List<Item> listItems, Date today) {
 // return list with ID and sum of the value for all the items group by ID and where the date equals the date in parameter.
}
```

So far I have looked at the Java 8 functions Stream and Collect and have been able to do this:

```
Map<String, Double> map = listTransactions.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Item::getId, Collectors.summingDouble(Item::getValue)));
```

This is working fine to group by id but I'm not sure how to filter by date now so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Otherwise I could do it with a basic loop but I would like to find a better way to do it, using Java 8 if possible.

Comment: Add `.filter(item -> today.equals(item.getDate()))` before `.collect(...)`?

Comment: This is actually a very good idea, do you know if this is possible to apply another condition on the actual sum? (like sum(value) > 1000)?

Comment: Stream over the result and filter to your liking.  Or put the result into a mutable map and `map.values().removeIf(sum -> sum <=1000);`

Comment: Thanks Misha! That's what I'm doing at the moment but I was wondering if I could do it in a better way.

Comment: How are you going to handle same Id values with different date values in this case?

Comment: isn't it the purpose of the filter by date?

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do it like so,

```
Map<String, Map<LocalDateTime, Double>> result = items.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Item::getId,
                Collectors.groupingBy(Item::getDate, Collectors.summingDouble(Item::getValue))));
```

But the result type is not exactly the same what you need. In this case it is `Map<String, Map<LocalDateTime, Double>>`

Anyway here's my question to you, How are you going to handle same Id values with different date values in this case? How are you going to handle that conflict?